# SQL Server query SAP Business One

Tags: sql-server

I've got some error in my SQL and can't figure out whats causing the problem. I am using Navicat to connect to a SQL Server 2000 (on Windows Server 2003). I run the following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
OCRD.CardCode,
OCRD.CardName,
OCRD.Address,
OCRD.ZipCode,
OCRD.City,
OCRD.Country,
CASE OCRD.GroupCode =
WHEN 100 THEN 'Kunde'
WHEN 101 THEN 'Lieferant'
END
FROM
OCRD
INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T1.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
(OCRD.GroupCode != 101) AND
(OCRD.GroupNum = 8 OR
OCRD.GroupNum = 7 OR
OCRD.GroupNum = 9 OR
OCRD.GroupNum = 6 OR
OCRD.GroupNum = 5 OR
OCRD.GroupNum = 4) AND
T1.DocDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
OCRD.Address IS NOT NULL AND 
(validFor = 'N' OR (validFor = 'Y' AND validTo IS NULL))
```

The following error appears

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Bad syntax near '='

I can't figure out why

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2003** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 on the horizon - so which is it really?=

Comment: It's 2000 running on a Server 2003. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    OCRD.CardCode,
    OCRD.CardName,
    OCRD.Address,
    OCRD.ZipCode,
    OCRD.City,
    OCRD.Country,
    CASE OCRD.GroupCode          -- you must not use a = here !
         WHEN 100 THEN 'Kunde'
        WHEN 101 THEN 'Lieferant'
    END
FROM
   OCRD
INNER JOIN 
   OINV T1 on T1.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
   (OCRD.GroupCode != 101) AND
   (OCRD.GroupNum = 8 OR
   OCRD.GroupNum = 7 OR
   OCRD.GroupNum = 9 OR
   OCRD.GroupNum = 6 OR
   OCRD.GroupNum = 5 OR
   OCRD.GroupNum = 4) AND
   T1.DocDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
   OCRD.Address IS NOT NULL AND 
   (validFor = 'N' OR (validFor = 'Y' AND validTo IS NULL))
```

There's no `=` at the end of the `CASE` line of code